# Disable MKmapkit mapView userLocation annotationView

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, userlocation

I have a `mapView` with `annotationViews` and the `userLocation` blue dot.

I am using the following code to get the blue dot:

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

The `annotationViews` are selectable and have callouts.

However if an `annotationView` is close to the user's location sometimes the blue dot steals the touch.

I can set an `annotationView.enabled = NO;` and it will show the annotationView but it will not steal a touch from a close by `annotationView`.

I would like to set the user location blue dot `annotationView` to enabled=NO, so it does not steal the touch of close by `annotationViews`.

I can set the title of the blue dot with:

```
self.mapView.userLocation.title = @"title here..."
```

But I cannot disable the blue dot.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do self.mapView.userLocation.enabled = NO?

Comment: If you don't mind making your own annotation view, you can override the view that gets used in `-mapView:viewForAnnotation:`. A lot of work though!

Comment: @Nathan Villaescusa, I though the same thing. Unfortunately trying 'self.mapView.userLocation.enabled = NO' results in an error: Property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'MKUserLocation'

Comment: @0xSina Unfortunately I want the annotation, the blue dot to be visible, just not selectable. Setting the 'annotation.hidden = YES' for the userLocation results in the entire annotation not being visible. Thanks!

Comment: @tc Overriding the annotation with a custom annotation is an option. However, I have not found a way to recreate the blue circle location accuracy pulse around the built in blue dot annotation. But this would be the fall back solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `enabled` on the user location's `MKAnnotationView` by getting a reference to it in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method (so you can be sure the view is ready):

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *ulv = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
    ulv.enabled = NO;
}
```

(There is no `enabled` property on the `userLocation` *model* object -- it's a property of the view.)